# Какой самый простой способ реализовать просмотр pdf без использования сторонних приложений?

Tags: java, android

Какой самый простой способ  реализовать просмотр pdf  из памяти устройства внутри моего приложения без использования сторонних приложений?

Comment: Написать самому кусок кода для чтения файлов даного формата.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через интент:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File( filename  );
intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile( file ), "application/pdf" );
startActivity(intent);
```

здесь вы должны будете выбрать программу которая будет использоваться для просмотра. Другой вариант - использовать библиотеку, [вот](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) например.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы именно моя программа открывала, и чтобы была возможность выбора какой файл открывать! Без использования сторонних приложений.

Comment: тогда только через библиотеку наверное

Answer (score 1):

Сначала проверяете , есть ли приложение. Если нету предлагаете установить.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri.parse("/Android/data/ru.myapp/doc.pdf");
intent.setDataAndType(v, "application/pdf");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
if (intent.resolveActivity(pm) != null) {
    this.startActivity(intent);
}else{
    Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.pdfviewer");
    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
    this.startActivity(marketIntent);
}
```

У меня не работало без флага `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` на некоторых Android.

Если необходимо показывать PDF внутри своего приложения. То, простого способа нет:

1. [Реализация PDF Viewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/tree/master/android-pdf-viewer/src/main/java/com/github/barteksc/pdfviewer)
2. Либо конвертировать PDF в HTML, и открывать в `WebView`.